# Wildfly Swarm with main not starting EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly-swarm

I am learning the concepts of building microservices with wildfly swarm for the last two days and setup a little service using EJB, JAX-RS, CDI and JPA to test some Java EE features. The service is running up, but only when I do not use a Main class and the packaging is set to **war** in the pom.xml.

If I use the Main class to add additional fractions, the service is not starting up correctly, the EJBs are not deployed and available in JNDI.

What is the correct way to startup a JAX-RS service with?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>microservice-playground</artifactId>
        <groupId>cgh</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>user-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>cgh.user.Main</mainClass>
                    <properties>
                        <swarm.context.path>${project.build.finalName}</swarm.context.path>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Swarm swarm = new Swarm();
        swarm.start();

        JAXRSArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);
        archive.addPackage(Main.class.getPackage());
        archive.addAsWebInfResource(new ClassLoaderAsset("META-INF/persistence.xml", Main.class.getClassLoader()),
            "classes/META-INF/persistence.xml");
        archive.addAllDependencies();

        swarm.deploy(archive);
    }
}
```

Comment: We're trying to move away from main() usage unless absolutely necessary.

With your main() content above, I don't see a need to use that approach. Using packaging type `war` for the project would be preferred.

Comment: This is a good decision. I have experimented with my setup and tried to secure (keycloak) the service. The information of how to setup the fraction without the main() was not in the docs. But as I check the docs today there the configuration parameters are described :) I will give it a try.

Comment: We're still working on making the docs better, but securing services with keycloak through project-defaults.yml is possible. Have a look at https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/security/keycloak

Comment: It seems to me that when using "war" packaging any configured main method is ignored. Maybe the docs can be improved at that point.